# GKE AUTOPILOT CLUSTER CREATION : pod cidr range restricted to /8 to /22.Can this be modified

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

Trying to use a subnet with a small scope of ips : 10.x.x.0/26 for pods with gke-autopilot . Autopilot default to /8 to /21 .However in standard private cluster ...able to use a /26 for pods .I s ther any way to configure this value for pod cidr range in auto pilot ? Is there any way in autopilot to configure pod ip nestmasks at /24 and above ?

Trying a /26 segment on autopilot ..it wont let me use it.

Comment: when you use /26 what is the notification or error message that you are having?

Comment: You might want to check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/flexible-pod-cidr#cidr_settings_for_clusters) for your concern.

Answer (score 0):

The mask in the `Cluster default Pod address range` has maximum value of `/21` when using alias ip and `/19` otherwise.

This applies to both standard and and autopilot clusters.
However, in autopilot clusters alias ip is used and can't be changed so it is always maximum of `/21`.

Note that this range applies to the default in the cluster, but can be overridden in nodepools.

I'm pretty sure you can't set it to more than that :)
Maybe the `/26` you are mentioning refers to the mask at node level, but this is automatically deduced from `Maximum pods per node` which can't be manually configured in autopilot since the nodes in the cluster is managed by GKE.